# Sql replace is setting other value to null

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey i'm trying to do some sql request but got a problem.
Firstly i do a replace request who filled my database.
After i do an update request that update some values.
And i'm doing another replace which is used to avoid duplicates, however some fields that were updated just before going to null because of the delete that is done before the insert (replace case)
How can I proceed so that the replace avoids putting some attribute to null and keep the values from the update?

Here is the sequence of the 3 queries that I make

```
REPLACE INTO all.serviceworker_subscriptions
        (userId, userAgent, getDisplayMedia) 
VALUES ('"+userId+"','"+userAgent+"','"+getDisplayMedia+"')


UPDATE all.serviceworker_subscriptions 
    SET dateDerniereConnexion = '"+socketDisconnectDate+"' 
WHERE userId = '"+userId+"'


REPLACE INTO all.serviceworker_subscriptions
        (userId, userAgent, getDisplayMedia) 
VALUES ('"+userId+"','"+userAgent+"','"+getDisplayMedia+"')
```

My field : `dateDerniereConnexion` disappear after each 2nd replace ...

Thanks

Comment: I think you should research upsert, and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you explain?

Comment: I don't understand the reason behind a 2nd `REPLACE INTO`.